# CSS - position fixed and bottom

Tags: css

If you `turn off` javascript on stackoverflow you will see the `noscript-warning` on the top

```
#noscript-warning {
font-family:Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;
position:fixed;
top:0;
left:0;
width:100%;
z-index:101;
text-align:center;
font-weight:bold;
font-size:120%;
color:#fff;
background-color:#AE0000;
padding: 5px 0 5px 0;
}
```

Question. How to position the alert on bottom of browser?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

CSS:

```
bottom: 0;
```

Answer (score 3):

See [Fixing position:fixed for Internet Explorer](http://tagsoup.com/cookbook/css/fixed/) for tips on IE compatibility in either top or bottom positioning.  Particularly, it's ugly when bottom positioned block scrolls up with the content, instead of staying fixed as expected.

Answer (score 2):

Forgetting about browser support, change:

```
top:0;
```

to

```
bottom:0;
```

Answer (score 0):

Put

```
html
{
    height: 100%;
}
```

in your CSS.

Answer (score 0):

`bottom:0;` should do the trick.

Just remove `top:0;`.